# Rails 4 on Openshift - gitignore directory wiped out on push

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, openshift, gitignore

I have a rails 4 app deployed on Openshift.com.  The app uses paperclip to upload image and xml atlas files.  These files end up within my public/assets folder.

(Example path):

```
public/assets/textures/1/someimage.png
public/assets/textures/1/someimage.xml
public/assets/textures/2/anotherimage.png
public/assets/textures/2/anotherimage.xml
....
```

Recently, I noticed that when I push any changes to my app code to the master, my assets directory contents gets wiped out on the deployed app.

In my .gitignore file I have the following:

```
/public/assets/*
```

Further research suggested I needed to run git rm --cached:

Running

```
git rm --cached public/assets/*
```

produces

```
fatal: pathspec 'public/assets' did not match any files
```

I thought maybe my .gitignore file was possibly not being tracked, so I added some comments and did a commit and found the change was tracked.

I even went so far as to go through codeschool.com's "Git-Bits" and "Get Real" courses to get a better understanding.  However, the the things I learned have not helped with this issue.

Any suggestions on what might be the issue?

Comment: Probably not an issue related to git. Those files are ignored by git, so git won't touch them unless you explicitly tell it to. My guess is that OpenShift is cloning an empty version of the repository and using that when deploying your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can only store data inside `app-root/data` directory in your OpenShift deployment and only when your app is in non-scalable mode.
It is not shared among gears if you have many of them in scalable mode.

See the [Filesystem Overview](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html) for more information.

Comment: That's an interesting read and good to know. However, when I launched the app about 2 years ago, I didn't have this problem. My mac crashed a months back and it whacked my SVN GIT and a few other tools.  Seems to be something related to the Yosemite upgrade.  After getting it back online, this particular app is the only one I an having trouble with, but it's also the oldest.  My other apps are not giving me trouble, but they are all rails 4.2 or higher and Ruby 2.x  This one was a 1.9 I believe. Since I had trouble with git in the crash, I started looking there.